# Does R transform() overwrite each value?

Tags: r

I need to update a value of particular column, if another column matches the condition. Here is the sample:

```
zz1 <- "or,d,ddate,rdate,changes,class,price,fdate,company,number,minutes,added,source
VA1,VA2,2014-05-24,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:50:16,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,ss
VA1,VA2,2014-05-26,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:03:44,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA1,VA2,2014-06-05,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:48:24,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s1
VA1,VA2,2014-06-09,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 15:37:35,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,s2
VA1,VA2,2014-06-16,,0,0,2124,2014-05-22 14:17:33,,,,2014-05-22 12:20:03,ss"

columnClasses <- c("factor", "factor", "POSIXct", "factor", "integer", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor")
dt1 <- read.table(text=zz1, header = TRUE, sep = ",", comment.char = "", quote = "", na.strings = c(""), colClasses = columnClasses)
```

The first column (`or`) value should be changed to combined value of columns `or` and `d` for sources equal to `ss` and `s2`.

I've tried to do it like below:

```
dt1$or[dt1$source == "ss" | dt1$source == "s2"] <- paste0(dt1$or, as.character(dt1$d))
```

But it returns an error `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

Now I do it with the following code:

```
dt1$or <- as.character(dt1$or)
dt1 <- transform(dt1, or = ifelse(source == "ss" | source == "s2", paste0(dt1$or, as.character(dt1$d)), dt1$or))
```

It works well, but I am afraid that it re-writes each value for sources not equal to `ss` and `s2`. If it is true, then how should I change my code to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, judging by your previous questions, you were using `data.table` until now, so lets keep it that way and use `fread` instead `read.table`.

So first step will be:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- fread(zz1, colClasses = columnClasses)
```

Second step, is to key your data by `source` (bad name for a column btw) and perform a *binary join* in order to avoid the (correctly mentioned by you) overhead of `ifelse`, namely:

```
setkey(dt1, source)
dt1[.(c("ss", "s2")), or := paste0(or, d)][]
#        or   d      ddate rdate changes class price               fdate company number minutes               added source
# 1:    VA1 VA2 2014-05-26    NA       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:03:44      NA     NA      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     s1
# 2:    VA1 VA2 2014-06-05    NA       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:48:24      NA     NA      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     s1
# 3: VA1VA2 VA2 2014-06-09    NA       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:37:35      NA     NA      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     s2
# 4: VA1VA2 VA2 2014-05-24    NA       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 15:50:16      NA     NA      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     ss
# 5: VA1VA2 VA2 2014-06-16    NA       0     0  2124 2014-05-22 14:17:33      NA     NA      NA 2014-05-22 12:20:03     ss
```

Comment: Thanks! Strange, but `fread` reads `or` column as `character`, when `factor` is given in `columnClasses`. So, the result `or` column has `character` class in your case, when in my case (when `read.csv` is used) I need to have `factor` finally. I can change `read.csv` to `fread`, but in result I get even even more questions. For ex., is it more effective to read it as `character` and then convert to `factor`? or, `fread` approach should be modified to get `factor` from the very beginning.

Comment: And, why `source` is a bad name?

Comment: If you want to modify `or` you have to have it `character` class. You yourself did `dt1$or <- as.character(dt1$or)`. After modifying it, you can simply do  `dt1[, or := as.factor(or)]` which will modify it *by reference*. Re your second question. `source` is a function in R, it is better to *not* call your columns or data sets as stored functions in order to prevent unexpected behavior.